# Get 1 Segment of a Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I want to get from my Array only on section.

This is my result...

```
(
    {
        foreName = FORENAME1;
        gender = female;
        id = 15;
        key = 12345678901;
        longName = LASTNAME1;
        name = FORELAST1;
    },
    {
        foreName = FORENAME2;
        gender = male;
        id = 52;
        key = 12345678902;
        longName = LASTNAME2;
        name = FORELAST2;
    },
    {
        foreName = FORENAME3;
        gender = male;
        id = 77;
        key = 12345678903;
        longName = LASTNAME3;
        name = FORELAST3;
    }
)
```

How can I search for id 77 and get the whole entry array for id 77 like the following example?

```
{
    foreName = FORENAME3;
    gender = male;
    id = 77;
    key = 12345678903;
    longName = LASTNAME3;
    name = FORELAST3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That result is an array, and you want the element who's id==77...

```
- (NSDictionary *)elementInArray:(NSArray *)array withId:(NSNumber *)anId {
    // there are a lot prettier ways, but this will be the clearest
    for (NSDictionary *d in array) {
        if ([d[@"id"] isEqual:anId]) return d;
    }
    return nil;
}

// call it like this
NSArray *array = // the array logged in the OP
NSDictionary result = [self elementInArray:array withId:@77];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```